# Use of permute package to calculate all permutations in a blocked design

Tags: r, permute, experimental-design

I want to calculate all permutations of a blocked design suitable for a Friedman test. Consider the following example:

```
thedata <- data.frame(
  score = c(replicate(4,sample(1:3))),
  judge = rep(1:4,each=3),
  wine  = rep.int(1:3,4)  
  )
```

Four judges ranked 3 wines and now I want to calculate every possible permutation *within* the data for every judge. I expect to see 1,296 permutations, as also given by:

```
require(permute)
CTRL <- how(within=Within("free"),
            plots=Plots(strata=factor(thedata$judge)),
            complete=TRUE,maxperm=1e9)
numPerms(12,CTRL)
```

However, `allPerms(12,control=CTRL)` produces the following error:

```
Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  : 
  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

I tried using the `block` argument, but it simply returns a matrix that repeats 4 times a matrix with the 6 possible permutations of 3 values:

```
CTRL <- how(within=Within("free"),
            blocks=factor(thedata$judge),
            complete=TRUE,maxperm=1e9)
allPerms(12,control=CTRL)
```

IMPORTANT NOTE:
I do have a custom function to obtain the result, using an adaptation of `expand.grid()` with `permn()` from the `combinat` package. I'm interested in where I misunderstand the `permute` package, not how I can calculate all these permutations myself.

Comment: More likely there is a bug in the code that my examples and tests don't catch. Let me take a look and I'll report back. I think I know where the problem is...

Comment: You're the man! especially because you saved me from feeling utterly stupid :-)

Comment: OK, the blocks bug has been fixed now. See updated Answer.

Comment: As a follow-up, I've also fixed the Plots version that was failing too, and updated my Answer accordingly. Version 0.8-3 of **permute** now works as you expected. Test cases have been added for both these (and uneven numbers of samples per block/plot) have been added to avoid future regressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples provided by @Joris identify two bugs in `allPerms()` that were not picked up by the current set of examples or unit tests (that'll be fixed soon too!).

The first issue is an obscure bug <strike>that I'll need a bit of time to think through a fix for</strike>. I have now implemented fixes for this bug too. Version 0.8-3 of **permute** now happily handles the `Plots` version of @joris' question:

```
R> p <- allPerms(12,control=CTRL)
R> dim(p)
[1] 1295   12
R> head(p)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    12    11
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    11    10    12
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    11    12    10
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    12    10    11
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    12    11    10
[6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    9    8    10    11    12
R> packageVersion("permute")
[1] ‘0.8.3’
```

The second is an oversight. `allPerms()` generates permutation indices, but internally it works block by block. In the case @Joris reported, each block has 3 observations and hence 6 permutations of the indices `1:3`. Once these permutation indices have been created, the code should have used them to index the row indices of the original data for each block. `allPerms()` was doing this for *every* conceivable combination of permutation types *except* the simple random permutation within blocks case. **r2838** fixes this issue.

`allPerms()` was also not replicating each within-block permutation matrix to match each combination of rows in the other within-block permutation matrices. This requires an operation like `expand.grid()` but on the within-block permutation matrices. **r2839** fixes this particular issue.

`allPerms()` works this way because it does not expect the within-block samples to be located contiguously within the original data series.

This second bug was fixed via [**r2838**](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=vegan&revision=2838) and [**r2839**](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=vegan&revision=2839) in the SVN sources on R-Forge.

```
R> require(permute)
Loading required package: permute
R> CTRL <- how(within=Within("free"),
+             blocks=factor(thedata$judge),
+             complete=TRUE,maxperm=1e9,
+             observed = TRUE)
R> numPerms(12,CTRL)
[1] 1296
R> tmp <- allPerms(12,control=CTRL)
R> dim(tmp)
[1] 1296   12
R> head(tmp)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    12    11
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    11    10    12
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    11    12    10
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    12    10    11
[6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    12    11    10
R> tail(tmp)
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1291,]    3    2    1    6    5    4    9    8    7    10    11    12
[1292,]    3    2    1    6    5    4    9    8    7    10    12    11
[1293,]    3    2    1    6    5    4    9    8    7    11    10    12
[1294,]    3    2    1    6    5    4    9    8    7    11    12    10
[1295,]    3    2    1    6    5    4    9    8    7    12    10    11
[1296,]    3    2    1    6    5    4    9    8    7    12    11    10
```

Comment: Thank you again for your very fast response. Works great!

Comment: I should also thank you @JorisMeys. The first issue is related to the problem I solved in r2839 and involves some code that basically (and poorly - as you found out) did what `cbindAllPerms()` does now, but in a very round about fashion. The solution to the blocks issue led me to this new solution so I should now also be able to solve the first bug pretty easily now too! [so] FTW!